# How to automatic transfer the values in another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Friends I am using MS Excel 2010 and I want As I type any value or word in a1 cell, it should automatically be transferred into d1 cell and a1 cell should get blank again. Please suggest me any way, formula or VBA coding to do that…thanks…

Comment: these codes suggested by jcmermu are working fine...if i want to include the entire range i.e. a1:a100 and d1:d100 then what should i do?? namely the value which i type in a2 should be transferred to d2 and a3's value should be transferred to d3 and so on...please help...

Answer (score 0):

This VBA code should work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    theRow = Target.Row
    theColumn = Target.Column
    theValue = Target.Value
    If theRow = 1 Then
    If theColumn = 1 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        wks.Cells(1, 4) = theValue
        Target.Clear
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    End If
End Sub
```

You have to put it *on the worksheet* you will use. Open View -> Macros, on the left column below **VBAProject** double-click the worksheet on the left column and paste on the right column.